# Why am I getting 0 coverage from Jest when running it from npm?

Tags: unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I'm trying to get code coverage numbers for a single Vue component, using Jest.

Let's say my component is `/var/www/html/path/to/Component.vue` and its corresponding unit test file is `/var/www/html/path/to/tests/unit/Component.spec.js`

In my `package.json` I have the following script:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --no-cache"
}
```

When I run Jest to get coverage only for my component like so:

```sh
npm test -- "/var/www/html/path/to/tests/unit/Component.spec.js" "--coverage" "--collectCoverageFrom=/var/www/html/path/to/Component.vue"
```

I get zero code coverage numbers:

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.019s
```

**Why am I getting this result and how can I get the real code coverage statistics from Jest via npm**?

Answer (score 6):

I've found the problem and a workaround for it.

In my `package.json` I have my Jest configuration and it includes:

```
 "jest": {
    "rootDir": "./",
 }
```

This means that Jest's root directory is my npm project directory. In my contrived example this is `/var/www/html/path`.

To get correct coverage values, I switched from using absolute paths to paths relative to the above root directory. So what works for me now is:

```
npm test -- "to/tests/unit/Component.spec.js" "--coverage" "--collectCoverageFrom=/var/to/Component.vue"
```

*Still odd that `collectCoverageFrom` does not respect absolute paths in my project.*

Answer (score 3):

I also had the 0% coverage problem when running jest with the [--config= option](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--configpath). The problem was that jest assumes the `configPath` to be the root directory and thus doesn't find any files to check the coverage for.

My solution was simply to go higher in the directory tree:

```json
{
  "rootDir": "../.",
  ...
}
```

Adjust the steps you go higher in the directories (like `"../../."`) or put the config file in your root directory.

Comment: Yep I had my `jest.config.ts` `rootDir` set to my `./__tests__` folder but changing that to `./` worked cheers. This didn't affect regular running of Jest either, just made the `--coverage` command work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, for another reason

I had this in my `jest.config.json` file :

```
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "**/*.{ts}",
  "!**/node_modules/**"
],
```

After changing it to this, coverage is reported properly :

```
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "**/*.ts",
  "!**/node_modules/**"
],
```

(The extra `{}` came from me adapting the configuration from a frontend project that had `{ts,tsx}`)

Comment: This worked for me as well! Thank you!