# Jest has stopped generating ICOV-reports . Coverage shown is 0% for all files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest, test-coverage

We are facing some issues in our react web application.

Our jest coverage report has stopped generating icov-reports suddenly and all files show 0% coverage.

Our react version is : 16.11.0
Jest version is : 28.1.1

Can someone please suggest some inputs that we can try?

Already tried npm cache clean, deleting node modules, package lock, jest coverage --watch all etc.
But nothing is helping to get the coverage details back.

Comment: Can you share you jest configuration? And what changed before you stopped getting the coverage? did you upgrade Jest or nyc/istanbul?

Comment: we dont use jest.config , we directly use package.json

jest : "^28.1.1",
jest-sonar-reporter:"^2.0.0"

Comment: Please check if [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321625/why-am-i-getting-0-coverage-from-jest-when-running-it-from-npm) solve your issue